# Call to undefined method when searching

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have MediaWiki 1.23.2 running on PHP 5.4.39 (cgi-fcgi) with MySQL 5.5.42-cll. it works fine except for ONE single problem. When i search for something i get the following error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method MySQLSearchResultSet::getInfo()
>   in /home/user/public_html/includes/specials/SpecialSearch.php on line
>   507

[SpecialSearch.php code](http://pastebin.com/8L1BHiwr)

Can anyone se what is causing this error because it only happens on special searches. Like i can search for "cookies" and it works, but when i search for "coo" the error comes up. In short it seems that this error ONLY happens when there is a "match" for something on the wiki, as long as nothing in the work i search for exists, it works.

Comment: Show header of `getInfo()` function in `MySQLSearchResultSet` class

Comment: Is this in the Mysql database or some other file ?

Comment: It's the class from where `$matches` comes to function. Try searching project for this class

Comment: So you're using the default MySQL search? Did you install any search-related extension or change any configuration?